# How do I undo the \usepackage{hyperref} command in LaTeX?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I accidentally included the `hyperref` package into my document and it messed up all the `\ref` commands I had inside of it.

After I realized what was messing with my `\ref` command I deleted the `\usepackage{hyperref}` command from my preamble. But now I have the problem that my normal `\ref` command does not work anymore. There is only a blank space inserted at the location where the number from the `\ref` command should be.

I have tried to google the problem for hours but was not able to find a good solution.

Here is an example of where the `\ref` command does not do anything but does not give me an error message either:

```
A schematic representation of the organization of the plate
can be found in figure \ref{fig:traplate1}.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Images/traplate}
\caption{Schematic illustration of the 96-well plate}
\label{fig:traplate1}
\end{figure}
```

Does anyone know how to fix my problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could also try to get it working correctly with hyperref.  The standard "`\ref` going to the wrong location" is usually because you need `\phantomsection` or to redefine the appropriate `\theH_counter_`.  But with only "it doesn't work", we can't really help you.

Comment: If my solution is satisfying, why not confirming it as the right answer? :)

Answer (score 4):

To reset a document completely, it is always necessary, to delete all the temporary files in the folder (basically everything, which is not the .tex-file), where you compile the document! There are some lists, that LaTeX reuses, which might cause the problem in your case.